# How to Use 2 Server Variable 'REMOTE_ADDR & HTTP_USER_AGENT' For Redirection Rule In PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, url, redirect

I want to merge `REMOTE_ADDR` & `HTTP_USER_AGENT` in a code.

Is it possible?

Code 1 for user agent redirect:

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$agents = ['agent1', 'agent2']; //array of predefined names of agents

if (!preg_match('/' . implode('|', $agents) . '/i', $useragent)) 

{ //check if current user agent is not enlisted
    header("Location: http://example.com/");
}
```

Code 2 for IP redirect

```
ipagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$myip = ['agent1', 'agent2', 'Ip-1', 'Ip2']; //array of predefined names of agents

if (!preg_match('/' . implode('|', $myip) . '/i', $ipagent)) 

{ //check if current ip is not enlisted
    header("Location: http://example.com/");
}
```

MERGE CODE IDEA: I want to merge IP and Useragent redirect. Should redirect if An IP or Useragent is not found for example. Thank you:

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$agents = ['agent1', 'agent2', 'IP-1', 'IP-2']; //array of predefined names of agents

if (!preg_match('/' . implode('|', $agents) . '/i', $useragent)) 

{ //check if current user agent or IP is not enlisted
    header("Location: http://example.com/");
}
```

Comment: What does "merge" mean to you? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: If you have error reporting enabled, which you should have... Then your very first like in your "merge" code for $useragent should cause PHP to generate an Error. Translated: "That will not work". That's not how Arrays (in any language) work. Take the simpler approach of dealing with each case and deciding if you need to redirect or not.

Comment: The first and second code works in a page separately. I am trying to make the code work as one single code instead of putting the two code in a code.      I want to use REMOTE_ADDR & HTTP_USER_AGENT in a code.

Comment: When I meant merge I mean to use two PHP server variable in a code